# Truffle solidity loader Not working with Truffle 3.2.1

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

I was using [truffle-webpack-demo](https://github.com/sogoiii/truffle-webpack-demo) but started getting errors since I upgraded to truffle 3.2.1. I found the [new branch of the same repo](https://github.com/sogoiii/truffle-webpack-demo/tree/with_truffle_3) and copied config from there. Which should be working, but now `npm start` gives me the following error.

```
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

Error in ./contracts/MetaCoin.sol
Module build failed: Error: You must specify the network name to deploy to. (network)
 @ ./src/components/AccountList/AccountListContainer.js 37:16-49
```

I have upgraded to the following versions of truffle, webpack-dev-server, webpack and truffle-solidity-loader

```
truffle-solidity-loader: "git+https://github.com/sogoiii/truffle-solidity-loader.git#1f1e213d52f033b6863218307b8968ae68220fe1"
truffle: 3.2.1
webpack-dev-server: 2.4.1
webpack: 2.2.1
```

Below is my **config/webpack.config.dev.js**

```
var path              = require('path')
var autoprefixer      = require('autoprefixer')
var webpack           = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var precss            = require('precss')

// TODO: hide this behind a flag and eliminate dead code on eject.
// This shouldn't be exposed to the user.
var isInNodeModules = path.basename(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..'))) === 'node_modules'
var relativePath    = isInNodeModules ? '../../..' : '..'
var isInDebugMode   = process.argv.some(arg =>
  arg.indexOf('--debug-template') > -1
)

if (isInDebugMode) {
  relativePath = '../template'
}

var srcPath         = path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath, 'src')
var nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')
var indexHtmlPath   = path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath, 'index.html')
var faviconPath     = path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath, 'favicon.ico')
var buildPath       = path.join(__dirname, isInNodeModules ? '../../..' : '..', 'build')

var provided = {
  'Web3': 'web3'
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?http://localhost:3000',
    require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    path.join(srcPath, 'index')
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: buildPath,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: srcPath,
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    alias: {
      contracts: path.resolve('contracts'),
      // config: require('../truffle').networks.development,
      config: path.resolve('truffle.js')
    }
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: srcPath
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: srcPath,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: require('./babel.dev')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: srcPath,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.sol/,
        loader: 'truffle-solidity',
        loaders: ['json-loader', 'truffle-solidity-loader?migrations_directory=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../migrations') + '&network=development&contracts_build_directory=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/contracts')]
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: path.join(__dirname, 'eslint.js'),
    useEslintrc: false
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [precss, autoprefixer]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: indexHtmlPath,
      favicon: faviconPath
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(provided),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'myEnv': JSON.stringify(require('../truffle').networks.development),
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}
```

**Here's my MetaCoin.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
import "./ConvertLib.sol";

// This is just a simple example of a coin-like contract.
// It is not standards compatible and cannot be expected to talk to other
// coin/token contracts. If you want to create a standards-compliant
// token, see: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens. Cheers!

contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 6000000000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) returns(uint){
        return convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

    function convert(uint amount,uint conversionRate) returns (uint convertedAmount)
    {
        return amount * conversionRate;
    }

}
```

**Here's my AccountListContainer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AccountList from 'components/AccountList/AccountList'
import SendCoin from 'components/SendCoin/SendCoin'

import Contract from 'truffle-contract'
import MetaCoinArtifact from 'contracts/MetaCoin.sol';
const MetaCoin = Contract(MetaCoinArtifact)

import Web3 from 'web3';

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')
MetaCoin.setProvider(provider);

class AccountListContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      accounts: [],
      coinbase: ''
    }

    this._getAccountBalance = this._getAccountBalance.bind(this)
    this._getAccountBalances = this._getAccountBalances.bind(this)
  }

  _getAccountBalance (account) {
    return MetaCoin.deployed()
      .then(meta => {
        return meta.getBalance.call(account, {from: account})
      })
      .then(function (value) {
        return { account: value.valueOf() }
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e)
        throw e
      })
  }

  _getAccountBalances () {
    this.props.web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, accs) {
      if (err != null) {
        window.alert('There was an error fetching your accounts.')
        console.error(err)
        return
      }

      if (accs.length === 0) {
        window.alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.")
        return
      }

      this.setState({coinbase: accs[0]})

      var accountsAndBalances = accs.map((account) => {
        return this._getAccountBalance(account).then((balance) => { return { account, balance } })
      })

      Promise.all(accountsAndBalances).then((accountsAndBalances) => {
        this.setState({accounts: accountsAndBalances, coinbaseAccount: accountsAndBalances[0]})
      })
    }.bind(this))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const refreshBalances = () => {
      this._getAccountBalances()
    }

    refreshBalances()

    setInterval(()=>{
      refreshBalances();
      return refreshBalances
    }, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AccountList accounts={this.state.accounts} />
        <SendCoin sender={this.state.coinbase} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AccountListContainer
```

Here's the **`truffle.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    staging: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8546,
      network_id: 1337
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the error `Module build failed: Error: You must specify the network name to deploy to. (network)`, I suspect your `truffle.js` file has not been updated to the new truffle 3 spec.

Review how the config changed at the [migration guided](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/upgrading-from-truffle-2-to-3#first-things-first-configuration). It should look something like.

```
    module.exports = {
      networks: {
        development: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 8545,
          network_id: "*"
        },
        staging: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 8546,
          network_id: 1337
        },
        ropsten: {
          host: "158.253.8.12",
          port: 8545,
          network_id: 3
        }
      }
    };
```